# Unable use countability argument in following problem

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

> Suppose f is analytic function defined everywhere in $\mathbb C$ and such $z_0\in \mathbb C$ at least one coefficent in expansion 
>   $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n(z-z_0)^n$ is equal to $0$. Then prove that $f$ is polynomial

I understood that for each $z\in \mathbb C $ there exist some $n\in N$ such that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$
There is hint available for this problem says that use countability argument .
I know that zero of holomorphic function is at most countable by Identity theorem.
Here we get each $z$ some $n$. It does not say about for all $n$ some $n$ exist .
I am not able to use hint.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir I seen That solution but as Isreal Sir suggested I could not use coubility argument.Please Help me

Comment: Did you read the other answer to the question?

Comment: Sir I got Now . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $A_n=\{z:f^{(n)}(z)=0\}$. The union of this sequence of sets is $\mathbb C$. Since $\mathbb C$ is uncountable at least one of the sets $A_n$, say $A_k$ is uncountable. This implies that $A_k$ has  a limit point, because any set with no limit points is at most countable. But then  $f^{(k)}$ is an entire function whose zeros have  a limit point implying that it is the zero function. It follows that $f$ is a polynomial.